# Why not all users in my wpf app are listed

Tags: c#, wpf

I made a chat program with the wpf application, but it does not list the connected people, only the first connected person appears in the list.

[image]

Here is my code.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WebSocketWpf.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WebSocketWpf" xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:Client.MVM.ViewModel"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="455" Width="805">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <viewmodel:MainViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>


    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <DockPanel>
            <TextBox Height="25"
                     DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                     Text="{Binding Username, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            <Button Height="25"
                    DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                    Content="Bağlan"
                    Command="{Binding ConnectToServerCommand}"/>
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Users}" SelectionChanged="ListView_SelectionChanged" >
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding UserName}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </DockPanel>

        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
            <ListView Height="380" Width="617"
            
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}" />
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBox Height="55"
                         Width="545"                        
                         VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                         Text="{Binding Message}" />
                <Button Width="55"
                        Content="Gönder"
                        Command="{Binding SendMessageCommand}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainViewModel.cs

```
using Client.MVM.Core;
using Client.MVM.Model;
using Client.Net;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace Client.MVM.ViewModel
{
    class MainViewModel
    {

        public ObservableCollection<UserModel> Users { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<String> Messages { get; set; }

        public RelayCommand ConnectToServerCommand { get; set; }

        public RelayCommand SendMessageCommand { get; set; }

        public string Username { get; set; }

        public string Message { get; set; }

        private Server _server;
        
        public MainViewModel() 
        { 
            Users = new ObservableCollection<UserModel>();
            Messages = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            _server = new Server();
            _server.connectedEvent += UserConnected;
            _server.msgReceivedEvent += MessageReceived;
            _server.connectedEvent += RemoveUser;
            ConnectToServerCommand = new RelayCommand(o => _server.ConnectToServer(Username), o => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Username));

            SendMessageCommand = new RelayCommand(o => _server.SendMessageToServer(Message), o => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Message));

        }

        private void RemoveUser()
        {
            var uid = _server.PacketReader.ReadMessage();
            var user = Users.Where(x => x.UID == uid).FirstOrDefault();
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => Users.Remove(user));
        }

        private void MessageReceived()
        {
            var msg = _server.PacketReader.ReadMessage();
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => Messages.Add(msg));

        }
        private void UserConnected()

        {
            var user = new UserModel

            {
                 UserName = _server.PacketReader.ReadMessage(),
                 UID = _server.PacketReader.ReadMessage(),
            };

            if (!Users.Any(x => x.UID == user.UID))
            {
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => Users.Add(user));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

UserModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Client.MVM.Model
{
    class UserModel
    {

        public string UserName { get; set; }   
        public string UID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Server

Program.cs

```
using Client.Net.IO;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace Server
{
    class Program
    {

        static List<Client> _users;
       static TcpListener _listener;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            _users = new List<Client>();
            _listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 7891);
            _listener.Start();


            while (true)
            {

                var client = new Client(_listener.AcceptTcpClient());
                Console.WriteLine("İstemci başarıyla bağlandı!");
                _users.Add(client);

                BroadcastConnection();

            }

        }

        static void BroadcastConnection()
        {
            foreach (var user in _users)
            {

                foreach (var usr in _users)
                {

                    var broadcastPacket = new PacketBuilder();
                    broadcastPacket.WriteOpCode(1);
                    broadcastPacket.WriteMessage(usr.Username);
                    broadcastPacket.WriteMessage(usr.UID.ToString());
                    user.ClientSocket.Client.Send(broadcastPacket.GetPacketBytes());
                }
            }
        }

        public static void BroadcastMessage(string message)
        {
            foreach (var user in _users)

            {
                var msgPacket = new PacketBuilder();
                msgPacket.WriteOpCode(5);
                msgPacket.WriteMessage(message);
                user.ClientSocket.Client.Send(msgPacket.GetPacketBytes());
            }
        }

        public static void BroadcastDisconnect(string uid)
        {
            var disconnectedUser = _users.Where(x => x.UID.ToString() == uid).FirstOrDefault();
            _users.Remove(disconnectedUser);
            foreach (var user in _users)

            {
                var broadcastPacket = new PacketBuilder();
                broadcastPacket.WriteOpCode(10);
                broadcastPacket.WriteMessage(uid);
                user.ClientSocket.Client.Send(broadcastPacket.GetPacketBytes());
            }

            BroadcastMessage($"[{disconnectedUser.Username}] Bağlantı Kesildi");
        }
    }
}
```

For example, when connecting from 2 clients, both people need to write their names in the left corner. But only one client's name is listed.

Comment: Where does your server connect to? Your code just says `new Server()` without any URL or IP address. Doing network stuff is quite hard nowadays due to firewall etc. Did you test that Server code? If you have Server code, do you also have Client code? Did you check the network with Wireshark or so?

Comment: It's connect there 

127.0.0.1:7891


_listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 7891);

Comment: By the way, I added the codes in the server section to the topic, you can check it from there.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is the localhost. does each client connect from different computer ?  Or are you starting more instances of the application from the same machine ?

Comment: Yes I'm launching more instances of the app from the same machine.

Comment: Your code is very unclear, you should only post workable code. You are referring to an object called Server, which is nowhere to be found in the example.

Comment: @HasanOzan No, we're not going to download your files.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in the `UserConnected()` and `RemoveUser()` event handler.

You access the `User` collection not in `Dispatcher`.

```cs
private void UserConnected()
{
    var user = new UserModel
    {
        UserName = _server.PacketReader.ReadMessage(),
        UID = _server.PacketReader.ReadMessage(),
    };
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        if (!Users.Any(x => x.UID == user.UID))
        {
            Users.Add(user);
        }
    });
}
```